# 2014/16 Mecha anime where the main character went to an island and a man with white hair popped out who he had to fight

Tags: story-identification, anime

This is an anime from a while back I remember catching an episode of it (not sure which). But basically it was like a mecha anime and they had to go to this island for some reason. Inside the island was all teched out and stuff and this baked white hair anime dude popped out and the main character was like “*** it was you???!?” And then they had to fight him?

He might’ve been an angel or something that they had to fight and it was like a task force of people fighting them? The style was pretty 2014-2016 and that’s all I can remember.

Comment: This is a nice description. Did you catch any other episodes? Can you remember why they went to the island? Why they fought? Who the white haired man was in relation to the main character? Who won the fight? If you remember anything else you can [edit] your post to include that information.

Comment: Can you describe the mecha?  Were they humanoid?  Animal shaped?  Stocky or thin?  Magically summoned, or physically transported?  Did they fly, run, or travel on wheels?  How were they piloted?